# Recursive class instance initialization for singleton object

Tags: java

Does the problem with

```
public class Elvis {         
public static final Elvis ELVIS = new Elvis();         
private static final Boolean LIVING = true;         
private static final Boolean alive = LIVING;  

public final Boolean lives() 
{
return alive;
}           
public static void main(String[] args)         
{                 
System.out.println("Hello"+ELVIS.lives());         
} 
}
```

has been solved in java 8.

As In Java 7 and previous version has the problem of not initializing the instance variable if it has been declared after the recursive initialization of self class object.

Comment: I see no instance variables in this code, only static variables.

Comment: i think `google` can answer better for your puzzles.

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: `public static final Elvis ELVIS = new Elvis(); ` this is a static variable so this will only be initiliaze once during the class load I think (not sure of the exact moment). But not on each initilization of this class. BTW, this is working on Java 6 so It seems not reproductible.

Comment: What problem? What is recursive here?

Comment: So as In This question there is problem of not initializing the Boolean LIVING and hence alive is also null and this problem is in all previous versions does it happens in Java 8 as well or it has been fixed?